# IC for measuring frequency

Tags: integrated-circuit, frequency-measurement

In my application, I need to measure frequency in the 1 to 500 MHz range. Since this frequency is a bit too high for microcontrollers, I am wondering if anyone knows an approach to solve this problem, ideally using off-the-shelf IC chips that preferentially takes in a frequency waveform and outputs the frequency through some digital interface.

Comment: You do not specify what kind of waveform a "frequency waveform" is supposed to be. In any case, I guess it doesn't matter since it sounds like an FPGA is probably your only choice. And if an FPGA won't work, then you are in analog RF circuitry territory probably.

Comment: Oh yeah, recommendations for specific part numbers are also off topic here.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to say what your waveform is, how much frequency resolution you need, and how often you need an update.

Comment: Fixing this question to not ask for a concrete chip but for an approach, seeing that it got a good answer and is on the verge of being closed.

Comment: @DavideAndrea - Hi, You just edited this question to add "or test equipment" to the title and question body. That is a significant change. As [edits are allowed to](/help/privileges/edit) "clarify the meaning of a post **without changing it**" (my emphasis), please can you link or quote where the question's author said that test equipment was part of the question? Otherwise I will have to roll-back your edit. Thanks. [Update: That edit has now been rolled-back.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At 500 MHz what's usually done is to use a lower frequency counter with a prescaler.
You should be able to get up to around 50 MHz with a [PIC micro](https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/frequency-counter-circuit.html), adding a [divide by 10 prescaler](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc12080-d.pdf) would get you to 500 MHz.
You'll need an accurate reference frequency, and careful attention to board layout.